# Is it possible to mount a single Flutter widget into a native iOS/Android app?

Tags: flutter, cross-platform

I am trying to figure out if its possible to mount a single Flutter widget into a native application (and ideally react native, too). My goal here is to build a component library in Flutter and allow anyone to build an app in their framework of choice but still be able to consume that component library.

I've found the documentation for generating an AAR of your module and mounting that inside of Android, but it looks like that mounts an entire flutter application inside of the android application.

Here are the docs Im referencing: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/android/add-flutter-fragment

I was hoping to find a way to create simple components and mount a single component inside of the Native android application (and ideally iOS too).